# Swift: how closure captures variables of value type?

Tags: swift, struct, closures, value-type

Take a look at the following code snippet

```
struct Person{
  var name: String
  let surname: String
  var closure: (()->())?
   init(name: String, surname: String){
      self.name = name
      self.surname = surname
    
   }
}

var person = Person(name: "John",  surname: "Lennon")
let cl = {
   print(person.name)
}

person.name = "Bill"
cl()
print(person.name)
```

the output of the above snippet is

```
Bill
Bill
```

Can somebody explain how this happens? I thought that since closure is reference type and `Person` is a value type then when the closure is created it gets its own copy of the `Person`(since value types are copied on pass), so modifying outer `Person` should not affect `Person` that is captured by closure, but it seems that it doesn't work in this way. I'm new to swift and value types, so please don't judge my question too hard.
Thank you
 P.S. I know that we can capture value variable explicitly using capture list and in this case modifying outer variable doesn't affect captured variable. The question is no about this. The question is about the fact that I thought that it should be have the same way even without explicit capture

Comment: @JoakimDanielson <b>This is because functions and closures are reference types.</b>  . Taken from official swift doc https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html.

Comment: Implicit captures doesn't create shadow copies. You have to explicitly capture to get that behavior.

Comment: It looks like Swift is just designed that way, extremely inconsistently. Nothing much to do about it, just accept it as it is)

Answer (score 8):

The behaviour you expect only works when you explicitly pass in a variable to a closure like this:

```
var person = Person(name: "John",  surname: "Lennon")
let cl: (Person) -> () = { person in
    print(person.name)
}
cl(person)
person.name = "Bill"
cl(person)
```

When you implicitly capture a variable in a closure, that variable is always passed by reference. If you want to capture variables by value, you need to explicitly pass them in.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you please explain more regarding `that variable is always passed by reference`. How can be passed be ref since it is a value type? Does it mean the the value type is `Boxed` somehow in this case in order to pass the ref?

Comment: @jonnyB_5531 value types still have a memory address where they're stored (and when passed by reference, a pointer to that memory address is passed essentially). Just think about how `inout` arguments for value types work.

Comment: Is “inout” correct example in this case ? As far as I know “inout” follows copy-in copy-out rules, so when the variable is passed as inout you still get its copy which can be modified inside of a function and then assigned to the same memory location

Comment: @DávidPásztor how to `explicitly pass them in`?

Comment: @YimingDong check my answer, I've shown it in the answer. `cl(person)` is how you pass in a variable. `let cl: () -> () { _ in print(person.name) }` would be the alternative where you aren't passing in the variable, just simply accessing it from the closure.